# Stored procedure for datepart using getdate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    sr.InsertedDate AS SMSDateTime, 
    sib.MessageText AS SMS_Text, sib.Remarks
FROM 
    SMSInbound sib                            
INNER JOIN
    SMSReceived sr ON sr.ReceivedId = sib.ReceiveId
WHERE 
    sib.MessageType LIKE '%ER%'
    AND datepart(day,sr.InsertedDate) = @Day
    AND datepart(month,sr.InsertedDate) = @Month
    AND datepart(year,sr.InsertedDate) = datepart(year, getdate()).Replace("@Day", day).Replace("@Month", Month);
```

I am to trying to write a stored procedure of this query, but this line

```
AND datepart(year,sr.InsertedDate) = datepart(year,getdate()).Replace("@Day", day).Replace("@Month", Month);
```

is causing an error on `datepart(year,getdate())`

Is anyone willing to help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: can u explain clearly what is expected output

Comment: I had resolved it. :)
Output was;

SMSDateTime      SMS_Text                            Remarks
2016-12-01      MSO=112581 Date=30-11-16  DOC contains errors.